# Histogram of a discrete vector?

Tags: r, graph, histogram

I have here a vector, lets say h=(14,14,30) of which I want to make a histogramm. For example there then should be a "2" high line at 14 and a "1" high line at 30. When i use hist(h) I don't quite get this result. Anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Comment: A histogram of a discrete variable is a bar plot. Have you tried `barplot(h)`? If `barplot()` is not what you were expecting, can you provide more about what your expected outcome looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the width of the bars.

```
hist(h, breaks=10:32)
```

[image: Histogram with narrow bars]

If you want the bars centered over the numbers, you can use

```
hist(h, breaks=(10:32)+0.5)
```

[image: Centered bars]

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for! Is there any way to get the "30" under the bar instead of right on the right hand side of it?

Comment: Yes,  I will add to the answer

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: I used max(h) and min(h) as the boundaries now and I get the following error: "maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x' ". I cannot figure it out what the problem is, I tried everything. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I think that you used `min(h):max(h)` where I used 10:32.  Instead try `min(h):(max(h)+1)`

Comment: Can I send it to you in a private chat - since the main question has been answered already.

Comment: I tried to chat with you, but it says that you need more reputation.

Comment: this is a bummer. let me try to enter the code here.

Comment: OK,  but I need to leave. I will check again later this evening.

Comment: histo<-function(w,s){
  #w...anzahl an muenzwuerfen pro serie
  #s...anzahl an serien
h<-c(0)
for (i in 1:s){
n<-sample(0:1,w,replace=TRUE) #simuliert w muenzwuerfe (1 serie)
#sum(n) gibt anzahl an "1" in der serie
h[i]<-sum(n) #eintrag h[i] des vektors h gibt anzahl an "1" in serie i
}
mi<-min(h)
ma<-max(h)
hist(h, breaks=(mi:(ma+1))+0.5,
     xlab = "Makrozustände (Anzahl an Kopfwürfen in einer Serie)",
     ylab="Häufigkeit von Makrozustanden in s Serien",
     main="Histogramm des Makrozustandes 'Anzahl von 1'")
}

histo(10,100)

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: OK,  The problem is that when using `breaks=(mi:(ma+1))+0.5`    the lower bound for the breaks is mi+0.5.   Instead, use `breaks=((mi-1):ma)+0.5`